# Find text with regular expression and get just a part of it

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a text with a regex, let's say "andres", but it must NOT be between `[]`

for example if text is:

```
s = 'andres [andres andres] andres [andres] andresX andres'
```

I should get the first, fourth, sixth and the last one, others have at least one `[]` so they do not match.

I tried this:

```
"[^\[]andres[^\]]"
```

a better example http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/5j3UM/8/

but it does not work.

Comment: Maybe `"([^\[]andres)|(andres[^\]])|([^\[].*andres.*[^\]])"`? It'll consider `[andres`, `andres]` or `[...andres...]`.

Comment: Why would you write your own name 7 times, and then try to match it with regex, shouldn't you already know what your name is ?

Comment: Javascript or Python?  You used both tags..

Comment: I too am interested in how this would be applied. What purpose does this piece of code serve?

Comment: @Sam I need it for both but I guess the regex will be the same

Comment: @adeneo my name is for the example, it could be any text

Comment: 2 passes on the string would work, first filter out anything between and including [], then use a simple regex to look for your text

Comment: @user3203010 could you explain it more in an answer?

Comment: @user3203010 I also need the possitions

Answer (score 2):

There is a useful pattern for doing this sort of thing in regex:

```
exclusion_context1|exclusion_context2|...|(stuff_you_want)
```

Where you can specify as many exclusion contexts as you want, and at the end capture the stuff you *do* want inside a capturing group.  I could explain further but really I'll just [link you to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-a-pattern-except-in-three-situations-s1-s2-s3/23589204#23589204) which goes into great depth about the above pattern.

So, then:

```
\[.*?\]|(andres)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jU7tJfO0jjQ7Yu2E)

Where our exclusion context lazily matches anything inside brackets, and otherwise we capture all the `andres` outside of that context.

Since I just noticed you wanted the *positions* of the matches, it might look something like this in python:

```
for m in re.finditer(r'\[.*?\]|(andres)', s):
    if m.group(1):
        print('{}: {}'.format(m.start(),m.group()))

0: andres
23: andres
39: andres
47: andres
```

Comment: the group at line 39 should write "andres" instead of "andresX"

Comment: oh.  well, just.. put `andres` into the regex in place of the previous capturing group.  Edited.

Comment: If if add "andres" it will only return (0,23 and 47), I would also like to put text with spaces like "andres arrieche"

Comment: forget my last comment, I thought you meant to put "\bandres\b" but now your answer is right

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant then.

Comment: I create an example which it fails. I'll edit my question to add it. I'll also remove python tag because my example is javascript

Comment: It's failing because you're replacing things matched by the main expression as well as the capturing group - you **only** want to replace things matched by the capturing group.

Comment: for example here http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/5j3UM/10/ it "works" but does not change the last

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
test string is:

```
$string = 'andres [an1dres an1dres] andres [an1dres] andresX andres' ;

$patern = '/\\[.*?\\]| /';
```

Comment: I need to specify a particular string, in the example I used my name but it can be whatever

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
\w+(?![^\[]*\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP7yV8)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
andres(?=[^[\]]+(?:\[|$))
```

- You may or may not want to set the case insensitive option.
- You may or may not need to set the ^$ match at line break option.

Explanation

look for any instance of the string which is followed by a

- Series of characters that is not a closing bracket and then by
- either an opening bracket or the end of the string.

Explanation from RegexBuddy:

```
andres not between [ ... ]

andres(?=[^[\]]+(?:\[|$))

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

Match the character string “andres” literally (case sensitive) «andres»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=[^[\]]+(?:\[|$))»
   Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^[\]]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      The literal character “[” «[»
      The literal character “]” «\]»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:\[|$)»
      Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\[»
         Match the character “[” literally «\[»
      Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «$»
         Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «$»

Created with RegexBuddy
```